# How do I solve Secret Note #16?

Tags: stardew-valley

I was wondering how I can obtain the reward from secret note #16. I have used my hoe, but it won't penetrate the ground where it says to dig up the chest.

Answer (score 2):

### Double-check whether you are digging at the right spot.

[Since version 1.3](https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/Treasure_Chest), you have to collect secret note 16 before you can dig the treasure, but you should be able to dig at the spot without the note. Make sure that you dig at the right spot:

> Dig one space to the right of the large boulder north of the Railroad tracks in the top left corner. See [image: https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/File:SecretNote16.png]